# Testing with Rspec codeschool level 3 challenge 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I have been battling this test way too long and I am not sure where I am stuck.  Here is the model I am trying to test:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iq
  validates :name, presence: true

  def genius?
    iq >= 3
  end

  def self.genius
    where("iq >= ?", 3)
  end
end
```

Here is what I am working with to start:

```
describe Zombie do
  context "with high iq" do
     let(:zombie) { Zombie.new(iq: 3, name: 'Anna') }
     subject { zombie }

     it "should be returned with genius" do
       Zombie.genius.should include(zombie)

     end

     it "should have a genius count of 1" do     
       Zombie.genius.count.should == 1
     end
  end
end
```

This is the part of the refactor that is working:

```
 it { should be_genius }
 #it "should have a genius count of 1" do     
 #  Zombie.genius.count.should == 1
 #end
```

Here is where I am currently stuck at with the refactor:

```
describe Zombie do
  context "with high iq" do
    let!(:zombie) { Zombie.new(iq: 3, name: 'Anna') }
    subject { zombie }

        it  {should include("zombie")}
        it { should be_genius }

  end
end
```

According to the examples this should work, but no matter what I try it keeps bombing on the include. I know I am missing something lame here. Thoughts or tips anyone?

Current Error Message:

```
Failures:

1) Zombie with high iq 
Failure/Error: it {should include("zombie")}
NoMethodError:
undefined method `include?' for #<Zombie:0x00000006792380>
# zombie_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) '

Finished in 0.12228 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec zombie_spec.rb:7 # Zombie with high iq
```

Comment: Ask yourself this: what does "it" represent in your two examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `!` to the `let` and change `new` to `create` in order to save the record.

```
describe Zombie do
  context "with high iq" do
  let!(:zombie) { Zombie.create(iq: 3, name: 'Anna') }
  subject { zombie }

  it "should be returned with genius" do
    Zombie.genius.should include(zombie)
  end

  it "should have a genius count of 1" do 
    Zombie.genius.count.should == 1
  end

  end
end
```

Comment: awesome. thank you so much for your help, i have been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what examples you are referring to that suggest your refactor should work, but the implicit subject `zombie` used in your first refactored example is an ActiveRecord instance and the `include` matcher you're using is intended to be used with a string, array or hash as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/include-matcher.

As for your second refactored example, I gather it's working because you've only indicated a problem with the `include`.

Comment: `be_genius` should work; RSpec builds a predicate matcher for anything ending in `?`, so `be_whatever` should call `whatever?` on the instance. I don't think this is always good style though.

Comment: I adjusted what I feel is working which is be_genius.  The issue is still with the include or rather testing the "zombie" is included with genius... thoughts?

Comment: Also, I just re-ran the tests so I could dump you the specific output.

Comment: @chrishough In the original code the subject is explicit: `Zombie.genius`. That returns a collection, which responds to `include`. The refactor changes the subject to `Zombie.new`, which is an instance, not a collection-it doesn't respond to `include`. You need to change the subject for the first example to `Zombie.genius`. This also shows how using the implicit subject is not always a good idea.

I'm also thinking you need to save the instance in order for the `where` scope to find it.

Comment: @zetetic after refactoring the subject to: subject { Zombie.genius } nothing works.  Thank you for your help, I appreciate it man. Any other tips?  If I change the subject, how would I change the tests?

Comment: @zetetic apparently it wants me to use let! but I can not get that first test they want to pass to pass.  Thoughts?